# Drawing texture mapped rectangle

Tags: android

I am trying to draw 2 triangles together as a rectangle and draw the entire texture over it which I thought would just be 1.0 coordinates. I get 1 triangle with a lot of tiny faded textures. Im very new to opengl and kind of lost what is going on with these calls.
Does anyone see anything obviously wrong probably in my QUAD class like I have wrong coordinates or drawing in wrong order?

```
  public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        private Quad myquad;
        private Context context;
        int texture[] = new int[1];
        private int width,height;
        int x,y;
        private long startframe,timediff,sleeptime,frameskip;
        private final static int MAX_FPS = 25;
        private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
        private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000/MAX_FPS;
        private static Direction move_direction=Direction.NONE;


        public MyRenderer (Context context){
          this.myquad = new Quad();
          this.context = context;
        }
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            myquad.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

            //turn on alpha blending
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
            gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

            x=y=0;
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
            width=w;
            height=h;
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix          
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glOrthof(0.0f, 320, 0.0f, 480, 1.0f, -1.0f);        
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            startframe=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            // define the color we want to be displayed as the "clipping wall"
            gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            // clear the color buffer to show the ClearColor we called above...
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
          //  gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
            switch (move_direction)
            {
            case UP:
                gl.glTranslatef(0, 1, 0);
                y=y+1;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                gl.glTranslatef(0, -1, 0);
                y= y-1;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                gl.glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0);
                x=x-1;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                gl.glTranslatef(1, 0, 0);
                x=x+1;
                break;
            case NONE:
                //gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
                break;
            }
            myquad.Draw(gl);

class Quad {
    private FloatBuffer vertices;
    private int[] textures = new int[1];
    private ShortBuffer indexbuffer;
    //private float vertices[] = {
    //      50.0f, 50.0f,  // 0. 
    //         100.0f, 50.0f,   // 1. 
    //        100.0f,  100.0f,   // 2. 
    //         50.0f,  100.0f // 3. 
    //};

    private float texture[] = {          
             0.0f, 0.0f,   //0
             1.0f, 0.0f,    //1
             1.0f, 1.0f,     //2
             1.0f, 0.0f        //3
    };

    private short indices[] = {0,1,2,0,3,2};



              public Quad(){
                try
            {
                    float[] coords={50.0f, 50.0f,  //0
                    300.0f,50.0f, //1
                    300.0f, 300.0f,  //2
                    300.0f, 50.0f}; //3

            short[] indices = {0,1,2,0,3,2};

            ByteBuffer verticesbuffer =     ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coords.length*4);
            verticesbuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertices = verticesbuffer.asFloatBuffer();
            vertices.put(coords);
            //vertices.position(0);
            vertices.flip(); 

        ByteBuffer idb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        idb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexbuffer = idb.asShortBuffer();
        indexbuffer.put(indices);
        //indexbuffer.position(0);
        indexbuffer.flip();
        }catch(Exception e)
         {
            Log.d("buffers","not working",e);
         }
    }

     public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
          //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
          //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.herowalkback);
         try
         {
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.herowalkback);

          if (bitmap == null) 
          {
              Log.i ("info", "bitmap could not be decoded");
          }
          //Generate one texture pointer...
          gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
          //...and bind it to our array
          gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

          //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
          gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
          gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);

          gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

          //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
          GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,bitmap, 0);

          //Clean up
          bitmap.recycle();
         }catch(Exception e)
         {
            Log.d("load texture","not working");
         }
       }

    public void Draw(GL10 gl)
    {   
        // set the color for the triangle
        gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

        //Enable the vertex and texture state
        vertices.position(0);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        vertices.position(2);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);


        // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexbuffer);

    }
}


public class test extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView glsurface;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        glsurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glsurface.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(this));
        setContentView(glsurface);
        glsurface.setOnKeyListener(watchkeys);
        glsurface.setFocusable(true);
        glsurface.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is called texture mapping, you need to get used to this type of situations.

So for example, remember that to map a triangle horizontally (the x coordinates) you used 0.0 and 1.0. With two triangles involved you need to divide the coordinate accordingly. So it is 0.0, 0.5, 1.0. And the same for the Y axis.

Ideally you would use a modelling tool like Blender to texture map your objects, so you don't worry about dividing 1.0 into an x number of triangles.

Comment: Alright thanks. Why would it only draw 1 triangle or is it drawing both its just I only see 1 because of the wrong texture?

Comment: There are many thing wrong with your code, more than 3 big things are wrong. Why don't you modify a working android example to get you started. And then come back to stackoverflow for further help. It would be a waste of time time to repair your code when there are fully functioning codes on the android developer page about this exact problem. Hope this helps.